# How can I get the Google Sign in Button to work in Xcode 9.3?

Tags: swift4, gidsignin

I am having trouble getting my google sign in button working in Xcode 9.3-beta.

Here is the code from my app delegate:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        //Initialize Firebase
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }


    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
        // ...
        if error != nil {
            // ...
            return
        }
        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
        // ...
    }
    @available(iOS 9.3, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
        -> Bool {
            return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: [:])
    }
}
```

And here is the code for my register View Controller:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

class registerViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var signInButton: GIDSignInButton!

    //Email_password combination
    @IBAction func complete(_ sender: Any) {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) {
            (user, error) in

            if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
            } else {
                //success
                let welcomeMessage = "Signed In"
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: welcomeMessage, message: "Welcome", preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "Default action"), style: .`default`, handler: { _ in
                    NSLog("The \"OK\" alert occured.")
                }))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    //GID sign in method
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
        // ...
        if error != nil {
            // ...
            return
        }

        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
            if error != nil {
                // ...
                return
            }
            // User is signed in
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    }
```

When I run this app, I can navigate successfully to my register view controller and my view for the GID sign in button loads successfully. however, nothing happens when I click the button. I've been working with this for hours and haven't gotten anywhere.

In the debug console, no errors come up.  but I do get at the top:

> "Unknown class _TtC4LEAF14ViewController in Interface Builder file."

I also get

> "Status bar could not find cached time string image. Rendering in-process."

I can't figure out what either of these are referring to.  I made sure to use the correct URL types, and have incorporated the pod files correctly.  My email-password combination works as well.

Comment: Please compare with latest stable version of Xcode (Xcode 9.2), so that we can determine if it related to Xcode 9.3 beta or not.

Comment: The "Status bar could not find cached time string image. Rendering in-process." runtime message is something that is showing up since using Xcode 9.3 betas; no such message in Xcode 9.2.

Comment: I do get the same log message, but have not any Google SDK included, I don't think, this is related to Google SDK / Login in particular, but rather an Xcode 9.3 related issue

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with Xcode 9.3 (official version) and Google login. I tested with Xcode 9.4 beta and everything works again.